# How do I determine the associated matrix $A_f$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I have the following linear mapping defined by
$ (, ) = (2 + ,  − ,  + 2)$

> Determine the associated matrix $_f$

How do you find the associated matrix from  $\mathbb{R}^2$ to  $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 2):

Compute the images under $f$ of the base vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$,

$$\begin{align}& f(1,0) = (\color{blue}{\star},\color{blue}{*},\color{blue}{\bullet})\\
& f(0,1) = (\color{red}{\star},\color{red}{*},\color{red}{\bullet})\end{align}$$
and place their coordinates (with respect to the base vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$) in the columns of the matrix:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{blue}{\star} & \color{red}{\star} \\ \color{blue}{*} & \color{red}{*}\\ \color{blue}{\bullet} & \color{red}{\bullet} \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! Highly appreciated

Comment: @at2018 You're welcome. It was your first question, but keep José Carlos Santos' comment in mind for future ones :-).